# How do you evaluate a nested array?

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I have a nested array and need to evaluate each item in the inner array and return 'yes' or 'no' if they meet two conditions. In the example below it should return ['no', 'yes', 'no'] but doesn't.

```
my_array= [[55,2], [62,3],[24,5]]

result= Array.new
my_array.map do |age, cap|
  if age > 60 &&  cap < 5
  result.push("yes")
   else
  result.push("no")
  end
 end
```

This returns the correct result but three times. I think I need to dig down into the second level of the array before using if/else but when I add the below to the code before the if/else statement I get an error message.

```
  `my_array.each do |nested_array|
   nested_array. map do |age, cap|
   if .... etc.
```

Comment: What is the error message you get? What is the code you get the error message for?

Comment: Depending on how you intend to use the result it might be more convenient to compute, `my_array.select { |age,cap| age > 60 && cap < 5 }
 #=> [[62, 3]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the evaluated result of `my_array.map`

Since `push` returns the array you just pushed to, you are essentially mapping your result three times such that your console output is `[result, result, result]` which expands to `[["no", "yes", "no"], ["no", "yes", "no"], ["no", "yes", "no"]]`

Try this:

```
my_array= [[55,2], [62,3],[24,5]]

result = my_array.map do |age, cap|
  if age > 60 && cap < 5
    "yes"
  else
    "no"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
my_array = [[55, 2], [62, 3], [24, 5]]
result = my_array.map { |ary| (ary[0] > 60 && ary[1] < 5) ? 'yes' : 'no' }
```